# Pandas Rolling Gives Unexpected Result Based on Window Size

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to calculate a moving average on a data frame similar to the one below:

```
ID   ID2   Date   Value
1     A    1-1-2020   1
1     B    1-1-2020   6
1     C    1-1-2020   2769
1     D    1-1-2020   0
1     A    2-1-2020   0
1     B    2-1-2020   1
1     C    2-1-2020   2461
1     D    2-1-2020   0
```

I would like to return up to a 24 month rolling average based on ID and Value.  So far, I have tried the following code:

```
df['rolling_avg'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=24, min_periods=1).mean())
```

When I run the script with the above code, I am curiously given 1107 for the first month and 1242 for the second.  My hunch is it has something to do with the way pandas determines the window.  To test this, I have tried adjusting the window like so:

```
df['rolling_avg'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).mean())
```

The script then returns the expected results of 2776 for the first month and 2619 for the second month.

EDIT:

My data are arranged in such a way that there is only one record per Date, per ID, per ID2.  I want a rolling average per ID per Date.

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question? What is your expected output? Not super clear to me.

Comment: My problem is that the function returns an unexpected result.  I would expect the average of the first month to = 2776 because 1+6+2769+0 = 2776/1 = 2776.  However, I receive 1107 for the result, which baffles me.